# How to see java external jars public functions/methods in eclipse

Tags: java, function, public-method

How can i see all the public functions that are in external jars with eclipse?
I have a bukkit(a minecraft server) jar. I know there are bunch of functions, but i only know one. How can i find out all the others?

(
Incase you didnt follow me. I am looking for other lines like this:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
```

)

Comment: Normally, jars aren't standalone, so the you can find `javadoc` with this jar. By the way, try to double-click this jar. If you're not sure, if it exists (it must be), you should google this: `<name of library> javadoc`

Comment: Use Javadoc. Alternatively if you are using some IDE, user Classname.<ctrl+space>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that jar in your build path for the project. Now from the project explorer explore the referenced libs, this will give you the view of all the classes inside that jar along with their private/public members and methods.

If you want to dig it little bit more then you can use jd-gui from following url.
http://jd.benow.ca/

This will allow you to decompile and will show you the full code of the jar.

mark it as answer if it helps you.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to use the javadoc.

I believe you can find the bukkit javadoc here: (I just googled it)

http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/

You can also attach source/javadoc in Eclipse and open them in Content Assist (CRTL+space) or in the editor. Even without adding the source/javadoc you can view all available members if you press CTRL+space after the dot.